# Call to WCF method with shared business logic - ...parameter is not assignable to

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an ASP.NET web application and a WCF service in different Visual Studio solutions which share common business logic (BLL project is added to both solutions). They are hosted on different servers.

When calling the following method of the WCF service:

```
List<RequiredAnimals> requiredAnimals=new List<RequiredAnimals>();
List<Animals>  animals=animalsService.GetRequiredAnimals(requiredAnimals);
```

...intellisense tells me:

Argument type `AnimalManager.BLL.RequiredAnimals[]` is not assignable to parameter type `RequiredAnimals[]`

Note that since I have turned on "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" in the AnimalsServiceReference configuration I am able to assign the return value of the WCF service method to a variable in the web site like:

List  animals=animalsService.GetAnimals();

However I an not able to do:

```
List<RequiredAnimals> requiredAnimals=new List<RequiredAnimals>();
List<Animals> animals=animalsService.GetRequiredAnimals(requiredAnimals);
```

Required animals in the BLL looks like:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class RequiredAnimal
    {
      [DataMember]
        public string Species{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
     }
```

And the WCF method looks like:

```
namespace AnimalsWcfService
{
    public class AnimalsService: IAnimalsService
    {
        public List<Animal> GetRequiredAnimals(List<RequiredAnimals> requirements)
        {
            List<Animal>animals= AnimalLookup.GetAnimals(requirements);
            return animals;
        }

        public List<Animal> GetAnimals()
        {
            List<Animal>animals= AnimalLookup.GetAllAnimals();
            return animals;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest why I can get a list of the shared business logic object Animal but I cannot pass RequiredAnimal as a parameter to the service?

Comment: where is the definiton of this method in your service GetRequiredAnimals?

Comment: Sorry, have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem in your code here, you are converting List to array.

```
Animals[] animals=animalsService.GetAnimals();
```

You don't need to do this. just go to your

**service reference--> configuration-->Collection Type-->System.Generic.collections**

It will be currently set to Array. Then you will be able to do as follows.

```
List<Animals> animals = animalsService.GetAnimals();
```

change this to

```
List<Animals> animals=animalsService.GetRequiredAnimals(requiredAnimals);
```

Note that i haven't converted List to array anywhere

Comment: Thanks I did that and changed the method call to: 

Animals[] animals=animalsService.GetRequiredAnimals(requiredAnimals.ToArray());

Predictably, intellisense how gives me the error:

Argument type System.Collections.Generic.List< AnimalManager.BLL.RequiredAnimal> is not assignable to parameter type System.Collections.Generic.List<RequiredAnimal>

Comment: So the problem is still that it cannot assign the type: AnimalManager.BLL.RequiredAnimal to RequiredAnimal

Comment: This is getting confused now. The Service and Website do share a common business logic and data model. RequiredAnimals is defined in the common business logic as is Animals. So why can I set Animal in the website to the Animal returned FROM the service but not pass RequiredAnimal TO the service as a parameter. Both Animal and RequiredAnimal are defined in exactly the same place and with the same DataContract and DataMember attributes. I have turned back on Reuse Types as I don't want seperate classes

Comment: After changing the collection type and turning Reuse types off then back on again and cleaning the solution, I no longer get the error. I think the service reference had generated the type even tho Reuse types was switched on. Thanks for your help.